# AFNetworking+Strange while download file with AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: download, afnetworking

guys.I have this piece of code in my file.

```
AFHTTPClient *_client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.1/file/download/"]];
[_client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
[_client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json;charset=utf-8"];
[_client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"*/*"];
[_client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Length" value:@"858663"];

NSURLRequest *request = [_client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"a.png" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"download %lld/%lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, _task.fileTotalBytes);
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //some code       
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //some code
}];

[_client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

below is the donwload file log output on the console.

23:55:13.731 MyP download 1258/858663 bytes
23:55:14.566 MyP download 815538/858663 bytes
23:55:14.567 MyP download 844994/858663 bytes
23:55:34.352 MyP download 847874/858663 bytes
23:55:34.354 MyP download 849314/858663 bytes
23:55:34.362 MyP download 850754/858663 bytes
23:55:34.364 MyP download 852186/858663 bytes
23:55:34.366 MyP download 853626/858663 bytes
23:55:34.372 MyP download 855066/858663 bytes
23:55:34.374 MyP download 856506/858663 bytes
23:55:34.375 MyP download 857946/858663 bytes
23:55:34.375 MyP download 858663/858663 bytes

why the last few chunk files spend 20 seconds?

especial 23:55:14.567 MyP download 844994/858663 bytes
to       23:55:34.352 MyP download 847874/858663 bytes

it's seems that the thread sleep 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.just remove the line [_client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Length" value:@"858663"];